# Динамичный список всех объектов на карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Доброго времени суток! Стоит задача сделать карту примерно похожую по функциональности на эту https://kaspi.kz/maps/branches/ (чтобы посмотреть нажмите сверху справа "НА КАРТЕ").

При переходе на карту появляется список, при клике на объект из списка детальная информация про объект(выбранную метку).

1) Подскажите что использовать, чтобы вывести подобный список в левой части (у меня все метки в Json файле, на карту их вывожу через objectManager)

2) При клике на метку или список, балун появляется так же в левой части карты. Это балун или что ?

3) Не очень понятно как при изменении параметров фильтра блок со списком и метки на карте обновляются, эти фильтры не являются частью API ?Запрос идет с БД?

Используя какие именно компоненты API они реализовали такую карту? в API есть много схожих моментов, но я не уверен, так ли это. Прошу подсказать способы решения задачи. Заранее благодарю !

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Подскажите что использовать, чтобы вывести подобный список в левой части (у меня все метки в Json файле, на карту их вывожу через objectManager)

Что хотите. Можете сделать [свой контрол](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control), можете поверх карты положить свой элемент (так сделано на kaspi.kz).

> 2) При клике на метку или список, балун появляется так же в левой части карты. Это балун или что ?

Скорее всего, они перехватывают клик по элементу.

> 3) Не очень понятно как при изменении параметров фильтра блок со списком и метки на карте обновляются, эти фильтры не являются частью API ?Запрос идет с БД?

Конкрентно на kaspi.kz при фильтрации в сайдбаре делается запрос на сервер. Но вы вполне можете делать фильтрацию на клиенте.
Если надо фильтровать метки на карте, то посмотрите в сторону [geoQuery](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery-docpage/).

> Используя какие именно компоненты API они реализовали такую карту?

Метки со своим макетом и выключенным балуном.

Comment: 1) "Что хотите. Можете сделать свой контрол, можете поверх карты положить свой элемент (так сделано на kaspi.kz)." - _Хочу сделать такой же список как на kaspi.kz, чтобы при клике открывался соответствующий балун_.                                              2) "При клике на метку или список, балун появляется так же в левой части карты. Это балун или что ?"

"Скорее всего, они перехватывают клик по элементу." - _можно плз поподробней, используют собственный макет балуна ? Если даже нет, я же могу используя собственный шаблон балуна, сделать так, чтобы они появлялись в левой части карты._

Comment: 2) Это не балун, они по клику `placemark.events.add('click', ...)` где-то меняют у себя верстку.

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, какие темы по изучать, и что пригодится сделать, чтобы при клике на метки placemark.events.add('click', ...), на верстке отображалась соответствующая метке информация, как связать метку на карте и информацию которую я где-то храню и буду отображать в своей верстке а не в балуне, большое спасибо за предыдущие ответы, они очень помогли продвинуться по задаче.